# The pygame code and the error is mentioned below:

Tags: python, pygame

Here is a source code of my **space-arcade pygame**. It's a quite simple one and doesn't shoots bullets. Only that we can move the player with the obstacles being moved as well. However, **the limit for the spaceship (player) to move in the screen has been set from x = 0 to x = 765 and from y = 200 to y = 480. But the spaceship somehow cross the limit for y-axis i.e it can move beyond y = 0 and y = 600, but only at some specific x-axis like when x is 10 and 590 something**. **How can i fix this gap** in the following python code:

````
import random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))  

pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")    
icon = pygame.image.load("space-invaders.png")  
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)  

background = pygame.image.load("background.png") 

player_image = pygame.image.load("space-invaders.png")    
playerX = 370  
playerY = 480  
playerX_change = 0
playerY_change = 0

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(player_image, (x, y))  

obs_image = pygame.image.load("cave-painting (1).png")    
obsX = random.randint(0, 800)       
obsY = random.randint(0, 100)        
obsX_change = 2      
obsY_change = 0.3      

def obstacle(x, y):
    screen.blit(obs_image, (x, y))  

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill( (0, 0,0) )  
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))  

    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            running = False  
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:  
                playerX_change = -4  
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:  
                playerX_change = 4 
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:  
                playerY_change = -4
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:  
                playerY_change = 4

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:  
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0  
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change  
    playerY += playerY_change 

    # Stopping our player beyond screen:
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 765:  
        playerX = 765
    elif playerY <= 200:
        playerY = 200
    elif playerY >= 480:
        playerY = 480

    obsX += obsX_change
    obsY += obsY_change

    # Movement mechanics for obstacles:
    if obsX <= 0:
        obsX_change = 3
        obsY += obsY_change
    elif obsX >= 736:
        obsX_change = -3
        obsY += obsY_change
  
    player(playerX, playerY)  
    obstacle(obsX, obsY)  

    pygame.display.update()```

Here are the source pictures used in the aforementioned code:

[background][1]
[cave-painting (1)][2]
[space-invaders][3]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZFLs.png

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxNs4.png

  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z97n7.png
````

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `elif`. You're code says (pseudocode):

```
If x is beyond or equal to 0 then go back to zero
If x is not beyond or equal to 0 but x is beyond or equal to 765 then go back to 765
If none of the above are true but y is beyond or equal to 200 then go back to 200
```

Do you see the problem? If x is equal to 0, then the y-checks never occur. Change the third `elif` to `if` to fix this issue. Here's the fixed code:

```
if playerX <= 0:
    playerX = 0

elif playerX >= 765:  
    playerX = 765

if playerY <= 200:
    playerY = 200

elif playerY >= 480:
    playerY = 480
```

Comment: Please post the complete code with your changes included.

Comment: @Brian done! thx

Comment: Thanks alot! THe code actually worked now :)

Comment: @MalikEbadullah If an answer helps you, please click the up arrow to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

These comparisons should be independent from each other.
By chaining then in a single `if/elif/elif/...` block, the checks
beyond the first only take place if the first check fails, and so on.

Given the nature of your problem, this is likely the cause.
Just replace the `elif` statements by plain `if`s: each check will
run independently and fix the limits it should guard:

```
# Stopping our player beyond screen:
if playerX <= 0:
    playerX = 0

elif playerX >= 765:  
    playerX = 765

elif playerY <= 200:
    playerY = 200

elif playerY >= 480:
    playerY = 480
```

Comment: Looks like you copied the OP’s code block and forgot to actually make the changes you suggested. Also, it’s fine to chain the two X comparisons to each other, and the two Y comparisons to each other, but not an X comparison to a Y comparison.

Comment: Thanks alot! THe code actually worked now :)

Comment: @MalikEbadullah If an answer helps you, please click the up arrow to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify you code. Use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to move the player smoothly, rather than the keyboard events `KEYDOWN` and `KEYDUP`. [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
playerX += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * 4
playerY += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * 4
```

Use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and [`pygame.Rect.clamp()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp) respectively [`pygame.Rect.clamp_ip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip) to limit the position of the player to a rectangular area.

```py
border_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 200, 800, 312)
player_rect = player_image.get_rect(topleft = (playerX, playerY))
player_rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)
playerX, playerY = player_rect.topleft
```

Or even shorter:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
playerX, playerY = player_image.get_rect(topleft = (playerX, playerY)) \
    .move((keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * 4, \
          (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * 4) \
    .clamp((0, 200, 800, 312)).topleft
```

Example code:

```py
running = True
while running:
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))  
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            running = False  

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    playerX += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * 4
    playerY += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * 4

    border_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 200, 800, 312)
    player_rect = player_image.get_rect(topleft = (playerX, playerY))
    player_rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)
    playerX, playerY = player_rect.topleft

    obsX += obsX_change
    obsY += obsY_change

    # Movement mechanics for obstacles:
    if obsX <= 0:
        obsX_change = 3
        obsY += obsY_change

    elif obsX >= 736:
        obsX_change = -3
        obsY += obsY_change
  
    player(playerX, playerY)  
    obstacle(obsX, obsY)  
    pygame.display.update()
```